# nltk taggedcorpusreader error

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm building a TaggedCorpusReader in NLTK (using ipython notebooks) to read in some POS tagged files from the ANC. (http://www.anc.org/) I want to get all of the adjectives from the tagged corpus. Here's what I tried:

```
anc = nltk.corpus.reader.tagged.TaggedCorpusReader(anc_root, r".*\.txt", sep='_')
tagged_words = anc.tagged_words()
anc_adj = {word.lower() for word, pos in tagged_words if pos =='JJ'}
```

All of the functions (tagged_words(), words(), sents() etc) work fine. But when I try to do the set comprehension, I get the following assertion error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-4ba2a8ab817a> in <module>()
      2 tagged_words = anc.tagged_words()
      3 print(tagged_words)
----> 4 anc_adj = {word.lower() for word, pos in tagged_words if pos =='JJ'}

<ipython-input-70-4ba2a8ab817a> in <setcomp>(.0)
      2 tagged_words = anc.tagged_words()
      3 print(tagged_words)
----> 4 anc_adj = {word.lower() for word, pos in tagged_words if pos =='JJ'}

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py in iterate_from(self, start_tok)
    400 
    401             # Get everything we can from this piece.
--> 402             for tok in piece.iterate_from(max(0, start_tok-offset)):
    403                 yield tok
    404 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py in iterate_from(self, start_tok)
    299                 self.read_block.__name__)
    300             num_toks = len(tokens)
--> 301             new_filepos = self._stream.tell()
    302             assert new_filepos > filepos, (
    303                 'block reader %s() should consume at least 1 byte (filepos=%d)' %

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py in tell(self)
   1364             check1 = self._incr_decode(self.stream.read(50))[0]
   1365             check2 = ''.join(self.linebuffer)
-> 1366             assert check1.startswith(check2) or check2.startswith(check1)
   1367 
   1368         # Return to our original filepos (so we don't have to throw

AssertionError:
```

I have no idea what this means! Can someone help me understand what the problem is here? Doing the set comprehension on the Brown corpus works fine...what is going on?